# Express middleware testing with race condition

Tags: node.js, testing, express, bdd

I'm having a trouble testing a middleware in Express that utilises promise (using Q library).

Here's an example that resembles my case.

```
var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
test('should return 404 status', function (done) {
  var req = httpMocks.createRequest(),
  var res = httpMocks.createResponse();

  myMiddleware(req, res);

  expect(req.statusCode).to.equal(404);
});
```

Let's say, `myMiddleware` makes a call to another module `using promise` that calls either `next()` on `resolve` or `res.status(404).send()` on `reject`.

I mocked the module for testing purpose.

how would I able to catch the end of `myMiddleware` on `reject` that does not return with next()?

Cheers!

Comment: does `myMiddleware` return a promise?  Or have a callback?

Comment: well, it runs async.mapSeries(items, function1, function2) and function1 calls a module that uses promise.
E.g.,

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to change `myMiddleware` to either return a promise, or making a callback.

You could do something like this:

```
// myMiddleware now makes callback with potential error
function myMiddleware(req, res, callback) {
    async.map(..., function(err, results){
        callback(err);
    });
}
```

Then in your test you can wait for the callback to test values:

```
test('should return 404 status', function (done) {
    var req = httpMocks.createRequest(),
    var res = httpMocks.createResponse();

    myMiddleware(req, res, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            // Handle error for tests
        }
        // Test your values now
        expect(req.statusCode).to.equal(404);

        // All done
        done();
    });
});
```

---

In this example the callback from `myMiddleware` only returns an error, because apparently you're not concerned with anything else.  In your case, we are mainly just using the callback as a trigger to test the values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tyler, here's some more context. As middlewares are stacked `myMiddleware` needs to be able to do either `call the callback, next()` or set the status code in the response and send it (which does not call the callback).

Comment: I think what your middleware needs to do is set the response AND make the callback

Comment: the reason why the middleware does not call `callback` is that once an error happens in the middleware, should it prevent going to the next one.